# Is there any reason to have multiple postgres instances on the same machine?

Tags: postgresql

So a large part of my work involves a postgres system spread between many machines. The way we've been handling sharding is to create a separate postgres instance for each database shard. There are about ~10 shards per machine, each is bound to a distinct port, systemctl service, data root, config, etc.

These are large databases which have the potential to consume a lot of memory.

I inherited the sharding system from a previous developer, but I haven't thought to change it because it has been functioning so far. Is this a bad practice? Are there any potential side effects?

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to have multiple PostgreSQL instances on a single machine to be able to start, stop and upgrade databases independently.

However, it is strange to see a sharding solution where multiple shards are on a single machine. That seems like a waste of resources. But perhaps the idea is to move shards to other machines later, when load increases.